# How to get Compliance Certification for Team recording bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are making our own bot to record team meeting, but after adding compliance policy, I am geeting this error("API call not allowed for non-Compliance Recording call").Do we require any Compliance Certification for recording bot. If so then how can we get this certificate directly from microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a vendor seeking to join the certification program, send mail to Teamscategorypartner@microsoft.com.

Ref Doc:-[Compliance recording for Teams certification programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/teams-recording-policy#compliance-recording-for-teams-certification-programs)

Comment: I have added the compliance recording policy but still recording is not able to start using azure bot.